# How to get the IP of all active machines on my LAN using SharpPcap

Tags: c#, networking, sharppcap

I'm trying to get the IP , port and MAC addresses for all machines on my LAN using SharpPcap,

I tried to ping all possible IP addresses according to my LAN base IP address as I thought that SharpPcap can capture the ping replay packet then parse it and get the needed info, but SharpPcap doesn't capture the ping replay packet at all!

Basically I'm using this code to capture the reply packets:

https://github.com/rubystream/SharpPcap/blob/master/Examples/Example6.DumpTCP/Example6.DumpTCP.cs

Comment: If you want to use pure .NET without SharpPCap, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492134/find-all-ip-address-in-a-network

Comment: Actually I need to use SharpPcap as it's able to provide me with the port and MAC addresses of the packet source!

Comment: You can also try to use Pcap.Net (http://pcapdot.net) as it also provides use with that information.