# How to quickly ping all ip addresses in a network?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

So I am making a network scanner in c# to show all connected devices to the same network as you. The way I am doing this is by doing a ping command on all IP's from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.255.

```
private void IPlook_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Properties.Settings.Default.nextIP += 1;

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.nextIP >= 255)
        {
            IPlook.Stop();
        }

        string IP = "192.168.0." + Properties.Settings.Default.nextIP.ToString();
        CurIP.Text = IP;

        //See if online
        try
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingreply = ping.Send(IP);

            if (pingreply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                string Hostname = Dns.GetHostByAddress(IP).HostName;
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Hostname, IP, "");
            }
            else
            {
            }

        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something Went Wrong", "Error Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

This is working fine but the problem is it is taking a **very** long time and making the program laggy. I have set the interval on the timer to 50.

Any help is appreciated.

Legitimate

Comment: Using Ping.SendAsync would be faster.  As it stands, you're waiting for each device to respond before sending the next ping.

Comment: You might also want to ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is arguably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13492134/397817. At the very least the most upvoted answer there might help.

Answer (score 2):

How about firing them all off at once (from an `async` method):

```
IPAddress start = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
var bytes = start.GetAddressBytes();
var leastSigByte= start.GetAddressBytes().Last();
var range= 255 - leastSigByte;

var pingReplyTasks = Enumerable.Range(leastSigByte,range)
    .Select(x=>{
        var p = new Ping();
        var bb = start.GetAddressBytes();
        bb[3] = (byte)x;
        var destIp = new IPAddress(bb);
        var pingResultTask = p.SendPingAsync(destIp);
        return new{pingResultTask, addr = destIp};
    })
    .ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(pingReplyTasks.Select(x=>x.pingResultTask));

foreach(var pr in pingReplyTasks)
{
    var tsk = pr.pingResultTask;
    var pingResult = tsk.Result; //we know these are completed tasks
    var ip = pr.addr;

    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}",ip,pingResult.Status);
}
```

You probably don't want to ping [addresses ending in 0 or 255](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Addresses_ending_in_0_or_255).

Answer (score 0):

You are running the pings one after the other. This means that you must wait for the timeout to expire 255 times. Start multiple pings at the same time. Using `await` would make a lot of sense here.

Also, unblock the UI thread so that the UI is not frozen while this is in progress. Many techniques are available for doing that. `await` happens to solve this problem as well.

I don't see why you are using a timer. If there is no reason for that simply delete all timer stuff. Use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I'm reading your code correctly you're allowing the timer to fire 255 times and are pinging exactly one computer in each execution. I'm not sure why you're using a Settings class to store the current iteration number.

You could loop over 1 to 255 and launch each Ping request asynchronously using the [`Ping.SendAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e6kc029(v=vs.110).aspx) method. There is no need for a timer.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13492134/397817) and answers/comments about broadcast pinging.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Can build your list of IPs using a for loop
            List<IPAddress> ips = new List<IPAddress>
            {
                new IPAddress(new byte[] {192, 168, 0, 1}),
                new IPAddress(new byte[] {192, 168, 0, 2}),
                // More ips in this list.
            };

            // Exactly what do you do with initiated tasks will depend on your specific scenario.
            List<Task> tps = new List<Task>();

            foreach(var ip in ips)
            {
                tps.Add(InitiatePing(ip));
            }

            // Needed so that console app doesn't exit..
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task InitiatePing(IPAddress ip)
        {
            // Note, this API is different from SendAsync API you are using
            // You may also want to reuse Ping instance instead of creating new one each time.
            var result = await new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip);
            // Process your result here, however you want.
            Console.WriteLine(result.Address + "-" + result.Status + "-" + result.RoundtripTime);
        }
    }
}
```